# How to make the Searching < ,> ,<= ,>= in Mysql database faster

Tags: mysql, database, search, indexing

I have a 20 GB database in Mysql. I want to carry out search operations involving <, >, >=, <= on the columns containing numbers(integer or float values).
For Example: In an Employee table I need to search for all the employees whose salary is less than 5000.
If I run a normal query it takes a long time.

Any suggestions, how can I make this type of searching faster. 
Do I use indexing or some other way? I have 2 to 3 columns in the same table containing numbers(integer or Float values) which are used for searching.

I did create an index on the column salary, but it takes the same long time.

Table structure:

```
          CREATE TABLE `newsearch` (
         `RowID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
         `salary` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
         `Employee_First_Name` varchar(52) DEFAULT NULL,
         `Employee_Last_Name` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Mod_Agency_Name` varchar(59) DEFAULT NULL,
         -- .....and 200 more columns which are not used for searching.

         )
```

Query For indexing Salary column:

```
      create index dollars on 
      newsearch(salary) using BTREE;
```

Comment: Index the columns you're searching against. Make sure your indexes fit in RAM. Run `EXPLAIN` on your queries.

Comment: Please include the query you are running and the structure of the table.

Comment: @zedfoxus Updated the structure and the query used for indexing

Comment: Remember that adding an index will give you no improvement if your column is NULL. See a reference on this thread: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43062/how-to-design-indexes-for-columns-with-null-values-in-mysql

Comment: @JorgeCampos my column is set to Default NULL

Comment: Sorry, I meant NULL the index would not be helpfull if your column is Nullable. I edited my previous comment.

Comment: Now update with the query (SELECT) you are using.

Comment: If more than something like 20% of the rows have `salary<5000`, the index will not be used, and it will do (as now) - a table scan.